# Get a vmodel value from a calendar field

Tags: vue.js

What is the vue equivalent of getting a value?
I am aware that the javascript version is: `document.getElementById("").value;`

Currently I have calendar field. I just need to get it's data.

Here is some snippets of my code:

I actually imported the calendar textfields from another vue file:

```js
import abCalendarFromTo from /* directory */
```

Two text fields are in one template, that's what there are two variables:

```
name="fromDate"
name="toDate"`
```

in my main vue page, I added these two:

```html
<abCalendarFromTo v-model:fromDate="aFromDate" v-model:toDate="aToDate"/>
```

In my script tag, I added:

```js
const aFromDate = ref<Date>()
const aToDate = ref<Date>()
```

my problem is that the code above shows more data than what I need. (shows current day, time, timezone etc) How do I make it so that it only shows mm/dd or mm/dd/yy?

Comment: Without seeing the `abCalendarFromTo` component no one will be able to tell

Comment: "_shows more data than what I need_", please give an actual example.  It _sounds like_ you're talking about the standard JS [ISO 8601 date time string](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date#date_time_string_format).  Using different `Date` functions you can format a given date string however you want.  The easiest may be `toLocaleDateString()`.  There are also entire libraries meant to help with date parsing and formatting, e.g. [day.js](https://day.js.org/docs/en/display/format) or [luxon](https://moment.github.io/luxon/#/formatting)